# Getting project category based on project key from jira rest api

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

We are developing a web project to get a list of project category for a particular project key for jira using their rest api and update it.
I can not find any appropriate api for the same. 
Has anybody done something like this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JIRA REST API documentation mentions this plain and simple.

### Retrieving project info

Use [GET /rest/api/2/project/{projectIdOrKey}](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/project-getProject) to get details about a specific project. This response will also contain info about the project category, ie.:

```
"projectCategory": {
    "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/projectCategory/10000",
    "id": "10000",
    "name": "FIRST",
    "description": "First Project Category"
}
```

### Updating a project

To update the category, use [PUT /rest/api/2/project/{projectIdOrKey}](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/project-updateProject)

You can include the id of the desired category in the request body, ie.:

```
{
    "key": "EX",
    "name": "Example",
    "projectTypeKey": "business",
    "projectTemplateKey": "com.atlassian.jira-core-project-templates:jira-core-project-management",
    "description": "Example Project description",
    "lead": "Charlie",
    "url": "http://atlassian.com",
    "assigneeType": "PROJECT_LEAD",
    "avatarId": 10200,
    "issueSecurityScheme": 10001,
    "permissionScheme": 10011,
    "notificationScheme": 10021,
    "categoryId": 10120
}
```